# How can i add a custom payment api to accept payment in my wordpress custom website?

Tags: wordpress

i am currently building an event website in wordpress where a user can pay for an event and enroll and can cancel the registration if he dont want to attend.
the the problem i am facing is that i am not finding a plugin which accepts the payment api which i want to integrate.. i am new to plugin development so i dont know how it will work.. anyone who can provide me these details

1. how can i capture the event details
2. how can i capture user details
3. how to save it to my custom table with related events
4. how to add the price field in my event (custom post type).
5. how to receive the response and than save it to my table.
6. how to show the registration and payment details in the wordpress
   admin panel.

i know the question cannot be answered in a line or two.. any reference will help or any plugin which will do this for me..

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to put the burden of payment security on your own shoulders; it is very heavy. If needed you might need to write some PHP to talk to the payment API you mentioned, without more details I can't say. What you should use if possible is something like WooCommerce which handles paypal and card transactions securely. If you can't use this, find a PayPal plugin and write the code needed to talk to the API yourself. All the best.

Comment: i dont have to look to the payment security.. the payment will be done on their server and we will recieve the confirmation in the return url.. i am not using paypal.. but it will be kind a same.. just wanted how to stitch all these things together..

Comment: In which case I need to know what API you're talking to, or at least the structure of it. If it is done by a less common business, they probably don't have a plugin for it so you'll need to write it yourself. If they do have a plugin it should be fairly straightforward to find.